# How to make my Ubuntu machine as router for “ zolertia z1 mote ” running Contiki ( Ping Border router from another PC)

Tags: 14.04

How to make my Ubuntu machie as router for (Zolertia) z1 mote running

```
**Contiki OS**
```

on it that connected with my laptop through USB cable I am running tunslip6 on Laptop, making network interface for USB connected z1. I can ping this z1 (Border Router) from my PC (through which its connected with USB cable)but I cannot ping it(z1 Border Router) from another PC/Laptop from same network. Can some help me on this I am stuck from long time, I modified these three files also

```
etc/radvd.conf
etc/network/interfaces

etc/sysctl.conf

but I think I couldn't modify them accurately.

Please some one help me on this I am in a tight situation
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the packet forwarding is disabled in kernel. You can check the output of the command:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If it is 0 then it is disabled.

You can enable it by:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If you still cannot ping from inside network, check your ubuntu firewall and that you specified the right gateway for inside network.
The iptables rules are following:

```
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE -s 192.168.2.0/24
```

The iproute settings:

```
sudo ip route del default
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

The 192.168.2.0/24 is the subnet where you want to forward the traffic and the 192.168.1.1 is your gateway. You need to enter all commands on the computer where you want to share the internet connection.

Inside your subnet you need to perform following commends:

```
sudo ip route del default
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.15
sudo sh -c "echo 'nameserver 192.168.1.1' > /etc/resolv.conf"
```

where 192.168.2.15 is your node from your subnet connected to the machine that is sharing the internet.

Comment: I am using the IPv6 , yes I enabled that packet forwarding it is in file etc/sysctl.conf  I modified it like this

Comment: I assume you have the net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1 in your sysctl.conf. How do look your iptable rules? Try sudo iptables -L
.

Comment: book-PC:/etc$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: I think "/etc/radvd.conf "file need to update properly

Here is output of my (PC:/etc$ sudo iptables -L)

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination     
    

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         



Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: Do you have the UFW enabled?

Comment: Do I just need to enable this (UFW)or should I set the rules also for iptables , my interface "tun0" is able to ping out side sites like ipv6.google.com , but request from out side not able to reach either my interface "tun0"  or  border router.       thank you

Comment: Either the border router or your tun0 interface is dropping icmp packets. But this should not prevent the inside machines to reach the border router. Have you tried hostapd? It is the linux equivalent to connectify. The how to is here: https://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/

Comment: Adding iptables rules will be sufficient.

Comment: Dear thanks for your support, I tried your link of Hostapd & I successfully made connection from my eth0 to wlan0 ,I connected my another device with this wifi hot-spot connection but I couldn't brows on my mobile after connecting , I set the IPtable rules in my rapberry pi too accroding to this  http://www.dickson.me.uk/2013/03/15/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-ipv6-gateway-using-hurricane-electric/ but it didn't work .. thank you

Comment: Hi Kukulo I follwod this link , that guy discussing the solution according to my problem https://sourceforge.net/p/contiki/mailman/contiki-developers/thread/0697654FDC044DB28AB0FDA250CFA3D7@Ginger/.. see if you get some point in that , I already tried that solution.

Comment: Can you ping the eth0 interface from the subnet? A lot of iptables configurations can be found on openwrt.org

Comment: Now I see the scenario: Are you connecting  the eth0 interface with eth0 interface of the other computer? In the computer stone age you would need a switch between the computers or crossed lan cable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response,  suppose tun0 interface & eth0 interface are on PC-A , another laptop is PC-B,  from PC-B I can ping the eth0 interface of PC-A & similarly PC-A can also ping the eth0 interface of PC-B,   PC-A can ping the whole mesh network through its border router using tun0 interface but problem in communication among the tun0 & eth0 interface of PC-A. I am replicating this project.
https://www.hackster.io/4348/zolertia-ipv6-6lowpan-ubidots-bcde84.

Comment: I tried this simplest example but this didn't work too with me,
https://www.wolfe.id.au/2014/03/02/configuring-a-simple-ipv6-network/
   I have both native ipv6 connection on  ethernet & ipv4 connection available on wireless lan. Me  Yes I tried  OpenWRT (latest distribution 15.00 something )with my partner on one of Huawei router but we couldn't install packages properly to make it as complete router.

Comment: man where are you

Comment: Looks like the radvd is not doing its job. Try to check that. You can try to capture packets with wireshark and enable verbose logging on radvd.

Comment: Added iptables and iproute commands.